# UK Passport Renewal Application for a dual citizen (UK & AUS)

Tags: passports, uk-citizens, australian-citizens, applications

Has anybody submitted their renewal application with just the identity page of their Australian passport and not colour copies of every single page as requested on the application form?

Are they strict about this requirement and what is the specific purpose as it is rather tedious to colour photocopy every single page of a passport.

**Note**: If you go to Australian Post to have your passport photos for a British passport taken, make that EXTREMELY CLEAR as the face size dimensions differ to the Australian passport requirements. It is also $2 cheaper at Officeworks and they work to international standards so they will probably check the requirements more thoroughly.

Comment: Perhaps it's what passes in the UK as discouraging dual citizenship. Or they're trying to figure out which UK citizens have been hanging out in questionable places.

Answer (score 8):

It used to be that you were required to physically send them the other passport(s) as well; I believe the full colour copy requirement is intended to be less onerous than having to send them the passport which you may have been hoping to use for travel while waiting for the UK one to get back to you.

It does appear to be a requirement in the latest [official guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/530370/OSOLGuidance0616.pdf), and is reiterated quite strongly on the [supporting documents page](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/overseas-passport-applications-supporting-documents-guidance):

> Remember if you’re a dual national, you must send a colour photocopy of your non-UK passport (every page including blank pages) as part of your application. You may be asked to show your non-UK passport at a later date.

[This response](https://www.whatdotheyknow.com/request/216367/response/552095/attach/html/3/32065%20final%20Battley.pdf.html) to a FOI request about foreign passports and UK passport applications is particularly relevant. It links to [this staff guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/118558/refusing-passport-facilities.pdf) on withdrawing an application which suggests that they ought to contact you first to 'request' you supply the missing documentation - which is more like a demand, as they can then stop the application entirely if you don't respond.

Answer (score 2):

I've just sent my soon to expire UK passport via Australia post to the UK PA in Liverpool, UK.  The requirements are unclear- stating no photocopies- but colour copies of every page of the non-UK passport are acceptable.  I photographed every page and then collated all 37+ pages onto 4 pages before pdf and printing. Fingers crossed that is acceptable, I'll update this contribution with the result ( hopefully a replacement passport with no issues)

Comment: Good news ( I think) DHL delivered 2 packages to the letter box of my registered address ( no signature required?). My housemate has said both 'feel' like passports so I am assuming that one is the new one and one the cancelled one. Conclusion (until  I have physically seen the passport) is that the UK PA accept photo/pdf copies.