# Getting a UK passport renewed when you have dual nationality and a different name in your second country?

Tags: uk, dual-nationality, passport-renewals

I recently applied to renew my UK passport. Since the last renewal I became a citizen of Costa Rica, which in common with other Latin American countries requires you to have two surnames (apellidos) in your official documents including passports. British people of course don't have two surnames, so it is the custom to take your mother's surname as your second appellido. The UK passport office won't renew a passport unless both passports have the same name, but I don't even know if it is legally possible to change my name in Costa Rica. Do countries allow you to include an alias or also known as in passports?
I wonder if anyone has experience in this.

Comment: "Both passports" is ambiguous here, because there are three passports: old UK, Costa Rica, and new UK. Which pair have to have the same name?

Comment: Why did you have to show your Costa Rica passport to the UK authorities?

Comment: @stewart hird What does your birth certificate say?

Comment: @ThEiLlEgAlaLiEn That is not correct.  [The UK is very interested in foreign passports](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/73784/19400).

Comment: @gsrorto because [they require it](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/73784/19400).

Comment: @phoog It seems to be a terrible regulation, since most countries will not accept a name change just to match a foreign passport. His best bet would be to cancel his Costa Rican passport, since the regulation talks only about uncancelled ones.

Comment: @stewart hird I don’t know if this will help, but a divorced friend of mine has just married abroad in her maiden name and is going through the process of getting a replacement British passport in her new married name. She has had to provide a notarised statutory declaration plus 2 documents, bills etc dated within last year showing her pre-second marriage name.

Comment: @gstorto I agree that it is a terrible regulation.  There is a widely distributed piece about unwarranted assumptions that programmers make about names, and one of them is that everyone has just one name. Another is that everyone has just one *legal* name.  The UK passport office obviously did not get that memo.

Comment: "I don't even know if it is legally possible to change my name in Costa Rica": even if it is, I suppose the new name would need to meet the same requirements as the name under which you naturalized.  That would of course continue to prevent you from adopting the name shown in your UK passport.  There's another possible solution, which is surely too impractical to warrant a full answer, which is to take the government to court and challenge the same-name-as-foreign-passport restriction as overly burdensome.  (Suppose you had *two* other nationalities whose passports did not match!)

Comment: @phoog it's a relatively recent policy that the passport office has adopted and the given justification is that if they let people have passports in different names it makes it harder to track people coming in and out of the country.

Comment: @Carcer perhaps they should do like the other countries and require people to use their UK passports.  Or they could keep a database that links people's foreign passports--and names--to their UK passports and names.  It's not rocket science. And seriously, there are people who have different names in different countries because neither country would allow the other name.  Are these people prohibited from naturalizing in the UK?

Comment: *The UK passport office won't renew a passport unless both passports have the same name*. How do you know this? Has the passport office actually rejected your application, or did someone else tell you this?

Comment: @PaulJohnson as per the guidance at https://www.gov.uk/changing-passport-information, "If you have dual citizenship (‘dual nationality’) and have a non-British passport, the name on your non-British passport must match the name and gender you want on your British passport. If it’s different, change the details on your non-British passport before you apply for a new British passport." You can find plenty of anecdotal accounts of people having their passport renewals rejected for this reason if you search.

Comment: @phoog the passport office does say *somewhere* that in the event that you're a national of another country that won't recognise your desired details, they will make an exception for issuing you a passport. (That has nothing to do with naturalisation - getting citizenship and getting a passport are two different things.) I do agree that it's really stupid, my partner is currently suffering under this policy as he's recently naturalised but getting his name changed for any reason in his home country is a bureaucratic nightmare and his old passport is still in his deadname.

Comment: @Carcer I realize that naturalization and passport applications are separate, but a rule that prevents a certain class of British citizens from receiving passports seems unsustainable.  If you have the details of the exception, it would probably be helpful to post an answer since requiring OP to have two surnames seems likely to qualify as refusing to recognize his desired details.

Comment: Try writing to your MP. This is the kind of bureaucratic ridiculosity that tends to vanish once an MP threatens to ask a pointed question in the House of Commons.

Answer (score 11):

I have subsequently learned that the UK passport office will accept having two surnames in my Costa Rican passport as long as I provide a letter from the Costa Rican authorities such as an embassy that two surnames are required under Costa Rican law for citizenship and passports. They will then issue a UK passport with a note that I am also known as...
I think this is a bit like having a maiden name included in a passport.
It is a requirement to declare if you hold a non-British passport.
I am just surprised that this is not a routine issue at the Passport Office. That fact that I have to go to the trouble of getting the Costa Rican authorities to inform the British authorities that Costa Ricans carry two surnames is astonishing. 
Thanks to all those who made helpful comments on this post; the problem will soon be solved

Comment: "That fact that I have to go to the trouble of getting the Costa Rican authorities to inform the British authorities that Costa Ricans carry two surnames is astonishing": That is only one of many astonishing things about this.

Answer (score 8):

The official British guidance on documents required for a passport renewal from abroad says the following:

> **Uncancelled** non-British passports: Please send us a colour photocopy of your non-British passport (every page including blank pages). We retain the right to ask for the original passport. We will let you know by email or post 
>   if we need you to send it to us.

Thus you could cancel your Costa Rican passport and then apply for a British passport without including your Costa Rican documents. Unless you've already declared your second nationality to the UK, they wouldn't even know you're a dual national and shouldn't have any further questions. Then as soon as you get your British passport you can renew your Costa Rican passport and live in peace for another 10 years.

Comment: +1 I have no problem gaming the system when I encounter such unreasonable statutes. In this situation wouldn’t even declare my second citizenship until after I renew my British passport.

Answer (score 7):

Taking a straightforward reading of the question, I think you've got things back to front. What you have to do is [request a new British passport with a change of name](https://www.gov.uk/changing-passport-information):

> If you have dual citizenship (‘dual nationality’) and have a non-British passport, the name on your non-British passport must match the name and gender **you want on** your British passport.

(emphasis added).

So the key is to understand that what you want is a British passport with (from a British cultural perspective) your new double-barrelled surname.

---

If your heart is set on a renewed British passport with only one surname<sup>1</sup>, I'm afraid that you made a mistake when you decided to acquire Costa Rican citizenship. As far as the British government is concerned, you have chosen to change your name.

<sup>1</sup> I don't take this as implicit in the question, but it seems that some people do.

Comment: Below that, it says “If it’s different, change the details on your non-British passport before you apply for a new British passport.”

Comment: @Traveller That’s not possible since he says the Latin Americans **require** two surnames. Thus either he changes his name in UK, abandons his Costa Rican Citizenship, or some other solution.

Comment: @ThEiLlEgAlaLiEn That seems very likely to be true.  The prospect of a country prohibiting one form of name when naturalizing but allowing it for a subsequent name change seems quite remote.

Comment: @ThEiLlEgAlaLiEn I don't know anything about Costa Rican names, but many people in the UK have "two surnames" - specifically, married people (of both genders) who find the idea of "one person taking another person's surname" objectionable. Aside from that, some UK families have had hyphenated double surnames for centuries, or even millenia.

Comment: @alephzero According to that snippet, the name OP **wants** on his British passport must match the name on his Costa Rican passport, but if OP wants a single surname on it, then it's impossible because of Costa Rican regulations.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, my take on the question is that what OP wants is a new passport and they haven't expressed any particular desire for what name should be written on it. I've edited my answer to make that explicit.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [guidance published](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/change-of-name-guidance) about changes of names on the UK government site, specifically the document ["Annex A: use of names in passports"](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/548220/Annex_A_passports_August_2016.pdf), if an applicant is unable to meet the requirement of using one name for all purposes for legal reasons, an exception can be made:

> 6.5 There  are  individual  categories  of  applicant  who  may  experience  restrictions  on  their ability  to  meet  the  identity  requirements  of  one  name  for  all  official  purposes. These  are primarily people who have dual nationality and who hold, have held or can obtain in the future a passport issued by another country.
>
> 6.6 Subject to the applicant being able to satisfy the following requirements, a passport may be issued in the name requested even where it differs from the name on the passport issued by another country. The following categories may be given exceptional consideration:
>
> > i.The law  in  the  applicant’s  country  of  origin  restricts  or  prevents  a  change  of name.    Where  there  is  such  a  restriction,  the  applicant  will  be  required  to provide  evidence  from  their  country  of  origin  that  a  change  of  name  is  not permissible;
>
> [...]
>
> 6.7 In  the  case  of  points  (i)and  (iii)  above,  a  (British)  passport  may  be  issued  and  an observation placed in the passport saying:
>
> > “The holder has a [country] passport, number [ ] issued on [date] in the name of [ ].  This passport is due to expire on [date].”

If Costa Rica genuinely will not let you drop the extra surname from your official name, and this limitation can be documented, it seems like that should be sufficient grounds for considering an exception when you apply for your passport. Costa Rica isn't strictly your "country of origin" but I suspect that should be read as your country of other nationality (perhaps the idea of a Brit wanting to get citizenship somewhere else is unthinkable to the government).

Comment: Yes, I think that piece of bureaucracy is the basis upon which I will be granted the exception. It is so strange, having lived in Latin America for many years where the norm is to have two surnames, dealing with the UK authorities questioning this practice. Outside of the Sceptred Isle there are millions of people with two surnames, if only the FCO but knew. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @stewarthird looking it up, I found anecdotal evidence that the naming conventions for married persons used on passports in places as close to home as France were causing confusion for the UKPO!