# New UK passport dual citizenship observation

Tags: dual-nationality, uk-citizens

I just received my renewed UK passport and one detail really troubled me. On the first page, they printed all info regarding my second passport, complete name, number, expire, issue date etc.
During the online procedure they ask if you currently hold a foreign passport, I of course didn't lie. So they request a full foreign passport copy in colour.
The details are under OFFICIAL OBSERVATIONS.

Why??? Why expose me this way to every foreign govt?
Perhaps the officer in charge didn't like me or had a whimsical wish that day, but I haven't heard of anyone else having this done to them, and I think it is weird for the UK to publicly publish info on their citizens.
Any ideas?
The only problem I had was that my photo uploaded online wasn't great. It passed, but the system complained about contrast or something. So in the process I added a hand written letter plus 2 professionally done passport photos.

Tnx cheers

Comment: Related: [Getting a UK passport renewed when you have dual nationality and a different name in your second country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/133131/3221)

Comment: Write your MP and ask them to change the law.

Comment: *Why expose me this way to every foreign govt?* --- *and I think it is weird for the UK to publicly publish info on their citizens.* The very purpose of the passport is precisely to **identify you** to foreign governments as an UK citizen so yes, they do expose your information to foreign governments. If the information on the passport was misleading/could help you to prevent a foreign government ban, then other foreign governments would be way less interested in accepting UK passports.

Comment: @SJuan76 I think you've missed the point - OP is a dual citizen, and sometimes being a citizen of certain countries can be problematic for travel.  It would be natural that there are certain trips OP may want to take on their UK passport *without being required to disclose* that they are *also* a citizen of another country.  (Consider an Iranian/British dual citizen who may want to travel to Israel without identifying as Iranian, for example).  The objection is that the UK government has stamped their foreign passport information directly into their UK document, making this impossible.

Comment: @SJuan76 "The purpose is to identify you as a UK citizen" does not seem in any way correlated to "they do expose your information". The passport itself is sufficient to identify you as a UK citizen.

Comment: I've recently (last year) renewed my British passport and although I had to send in my other nationality passport, there wasn't any mention on my British passport about it.

Answer (score 44):

HM Passport Office will place this observation in your passport when your name in your British passport is different to the name in your other nationality passport, and it is believed to be difficult or impossible for you to change the name in the other nationality documents to match your official name in your British documents.

Section 6 in [Annex A: use of names in passports](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/548220/Annex_A_passports_August_2016.pdf) of UK [change of name guidance for official documents](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/change-of-name-guidance) covers this scenario in depth and you may wish to read it in its entirety; the sections most pertinent to your question are:

> 6.5 There  are  individual  categories  of  applicant  who  may  experience  restrictions  on  their ability  to  meet  the  identity  requirements  of  one  name  for  all  official  purposes.    These  are primarily people who have dual nationality and who hold, have held or can obtain in the future a passport issued by another country.
>
> 6.6 Subject to the applicant being able to satisfy the following requirements, a passport may be issued in the name requested even where it differs from the name on the passport issued by another country. The following categories may be given exceptional consideration:
>
> i. The law  in  the  applicant’s  country  of  origin  restricts  or  prevents  a  change  of name.    Where  there  is  such  a  restriction,  the  applicant  will  be  required  to provide  evidence  from  their  country  of  origin  that  a  change  of  name  is  not permissible;
>
> ii. The  country  of  origin  does  not  permit  dual  nationality  meaning  alignment  of documentation  will  not  be  possible,  the  applicant  will  be  required  to  provide confirmation   from   the   country   of   origin   that   their   citizenship   has   been cancelled;
>
> iii. Where there is a requirement for the person to travel to their country of origin in  order  to  change  their  name,  and  due  to  exceptional  circumstances  in  their country of origin, they would be placed at a high level of risk;
>
> ...
>
> 6.7 In  the  case  of  points  (i) and  (iii)  above,  a  (British)  passport  may  be  issued  and  an observation placed in the passport saying:  “The holder has a [country] passport, number [ ] issued on [date] in the name of [ ].  This passport is due to expire on [date].”
>
> ...
>
> 6.13 The British passport will not routinely contain an observation of other passports held by a dual national unless by exception (see paragraph 6 above) it is in a different name. It is a matter for the passport applicant to raise at the point of application whether providing details of existing or previous overseas passports causes any particular concern.

My guess would be that you have two surnames (apellidos) in your other nationality and that the name the UK considers your official name lacks one or more of those names.

Comment: amazing information, MH !  who knew?

Comment: What if he simply hadn't mentioned his second nationality? Would there have been any way for them to find out?

Comment: @user13267 you might be correct, but **if** they ever find out, the OP may get into huge problems