# Can I apply for Observation to be removed from my UK passport

Tags: uk, passports, dual-nationality

I have just recently apply for change of name on my UK passport,  and it was printed with an observation detailing my other Nationality with my old name shown.

I want to ask whether it is possible to request for the observation to be removed in my UK passport, once after I have updated my other Nationality with my new name to match my UK passport?

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/153364/new-uk-passport-dual-citizenship-observation