# My BNO passport lists my other passports under "observations." Must I bring those other passports whenever I use the BNO one?

Tags: passports, uk-citizens, hong-kong-citizens

HM Passport Office has issued me a [British National (Overseas)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_National_(Overseas)_passport) passport. I also have a Hong Kong passport, but I do not have actual British citizenship, any UK Visa, nor right to abode in the UK.

As [others](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/153369) have [mentioned](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/133192), my BNO passport lists my other passports under the "official observations" section, but I'd prefer to be able to travel without disclosing this information all the time.

Must I carry all those other passports on me if I travel on the BNO passport? After an immigration officer sees the BNO passport and its official observations, will the officer want to see all my other passports listed there?

What if I use BNO when I travel to a country other than the U.K.? For example, if I were to travel to Japan on my BNO passport, would a Japanese immigration officer expect to be able to see the passports listed in this official observations section?

Answer (score 10):

No. It's hard to prove a negative, but multiple citizens are not expected to show all their passports when entering a country.

Comment: If you want to be really safe carry the passports you are not using in a secure pocket in your carry-on, where they will not be in the way, for a few trips. Do not present or even mention them. I do not think you will be asked for them.